# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap 4 with my angular installation. i've run
npm install --save bootstrap@next but i have a break at runtime :

```
./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","plugins":[null,null,null],"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:270:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:185:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:197:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:224:20)
    at LazyResult.async (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:221:27)
    at LazyResult.then (C:\xampp\htdocs\tick_master_angular\web\node_modules\postcss-loader\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:127:21)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css 3:10-190
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: I am getting the issue with final verison of the     "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",

Answer (score 14):

The issue could be that you got the latest build with some bug. I noticed that bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 is causing this issue, but not bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2. Check if yours is the same. Try uninstalling that and run something with a specific version.

`npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6`

This resolved my problem.

Comment: I stick to the newest version. As a temporary workaround, I added the bootstrap stylesheed in head of index.html, but kept the javascript stuff in .angular-cli.json.

Answer (score 12):

Bootstrap new version come which is v4.0.0-beta.2 and your package.json has ^bootstrap4.0.0-alpha.6 so new bootstrap version wants browsers list dependency.

To run your app remove lastest version tag (^) & run npm install command

Answer (score 7):

For Bootstrap 4.0.0 (release) I have to upgrade the CLI to 1.6.5 — and it works!

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I've upgraded to Angular CLI 1.7.x and it started working fine. I recommend this solution. I mean upgrading the Angular CLI and it should work for you!

Another workaround is deleting the below lines from **node_modules/bootstrap/package.json**

```
"browserslist": [
"last 1 major version", <----- delete this line
">= 1%", <----- delete this line
"Chrome >= 45",
"Firefox >= 38",
"Edge >= 12",
"Explorer >= 10",
"iOS >= 9",
"Safari >= 9",
"Android >= 4.4",
"Opera >= 30"
],
```

Comment: I faced the same issue and  I deleted the "browserslist" element and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Was having same issue changed my dependency in package.json from this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

to (changing "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2" to a stable version)

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

then,run:
npm install
ng serve

problem solved.!!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't use CSS anymore. In this version the SCSS is used. So instead of importing `'~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.css'`, 
you should import `'~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Bootstrap 4.1.1. Solution is to change Boostrap version to 4.0.0-beta.2 (without the caret) in `package.json` then run

```
npm install 
ng serve
```

And also add `import "~bootstrap/dist/css.bootstrap.css"` in your `style.css` file.

Answer (score -1):

It works now without workaround with *Angular CLI: 1.6.5*. Angular CLI has been depending on an incompatible version of autoprefixer (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020)

Verify version by typing *ng --version*. Do not foget to update your dev dependency in package.json:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
```

Comment: I'm using cli v 1.6.5 & bootstrap 4.0.0 and this doesn't work for me

Comment: Local and global version? Latest version of node.js?

Comment: local and global versions of angular/cli were 1.6.5, node was v 6.11 I believe

Answer (score -1):

For those still having problems:

Manually remove the url to bootsrap CSS from angular-cli.json

```
  "styles":
  [
    **"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",**
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",    
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

Comment: this works but how to make it work without removeing