# production compilation of angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to compile my angular application for production. I issued the below command:

```
ng build --prod
```

I got several errors related to bootstrap:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (C:\frontend\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
```

Not sure what I need to do to fix these errors. When I issued the command

```
ng serve
```

the application compiled successfully with ng serve. Below is my Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular5-time-picker": "^1.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^2.9.6",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try to run npm install

Comment: try to update the bootstrap version to "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update the bootstrap version to "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '**^**' from the `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"` or update the Angular CLI to ver 1.7. The problem is with the version of the autoprefixer that is incompatible with the updated Bootstrap.

[BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016668/browserslisterror-unknown-browser-major)

Comment: I tried removing the "^" sign and compiled again. still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Updating bootstrap to 4.1.3 will fix the issue. (`"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"`).

This is discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020#issuecomment-410732237).